# How do you insert an inline verbatim?

Tags: macros, sectioning, verbatim

I'm trying to add an inline verbatim into a `\paragraph`?

Was wondering how do you do that?

Comment: See: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=verbwithin

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need a work-around, since [verbatim text is not allowed as arguments to a macro](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-verbwithin) in general. [`verbdef`](http://ctan.org/verbdef) is one such work-around:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbdef}% http://ctan.org/pkg/verbdef
\verbdef{\vtext}{verb text}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Here is some \vtext.}
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Similar functionality is provided by [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb). You could also try [`cprotect`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cprotect):

```
\usepackage{cprotect}% http://ctan.org/pkg/cprotect
%...
\cprotect\paragraph{Here is some \verb|verb text|.}
```

Comment: hmmm... is there another way that I don't have to install the package? I know its rather trivial to install it but just wondering... I'm using MacTex distribution

Comment: Most of these package should be distributed with MacTeX. Moreover, the provided sources shows how to install the package (under the "Getting it" heading).

Comment: Does `verbdef` support multiline statements? I'm getting `Undefined control sequence }` iff the second argument of ''\verbdef'' contains a line break.

Comment: @KarlRichter: Off the cuff I would say yes. To get around that, you can store the content in a box, as in `\newsavebox{\mybox}\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}\begin{verbatim} ... \end{verbatim}\end{lrbox} \usebox{\mybox}`. But there are other packages you can use as well, like [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) for example.