# How to use \verb inside \IfLanguageName - Error \verb ended by end of line. }{}

Tags: verbatim, languages

I want to use `\verb` inside of `\IfLanguageName`. But I get the error message `\verb ended by end of line. ...ame{english}{... \verb| echo Hello | ...}{}`. I want to show only one language at the same time.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{iflang}
\begin{document}
\setlanguage{english}

\IfLanguageName{swedish}{... \verb| echo Hello | ...}{}
\IfLanguageName{english}{... \verb| echo Hello | ...}{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2791 … on second thought, this may be more relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37326

Comment: Special case of [errors - How to put \verb command inside of \textbf{} block? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24574/how-to-put-verb-command-inside-of-textbf-block/640353#comment48026_24574)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define an environment. By defining `\Stop` to be the same as `\fi` we get a manageable syntax.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[swedish,english]{babel}

\usepackage{iflang}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{languageswitch}
 {\expandafter\let\csname Start@\languagename\endcsname\@empty}
 {\ignorespacesafterend}
\newcommand{\Start}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{Start@#1}{\iffalse}{\iftrue\ignorespaces}%
}
\let\Stop\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{English}

\begin{languageswitch}
\Start{swedish}
... \verb| echo svenska | ...
\Stop
\Start{english}
... \verb| echo English | ...
\Stop
\end{languageswitch}

\section{Swedish}

\selectlanguage{swedish}

\begin{languageswitch}
\Start{swedish}
... \verb| echo svenska | ...
\Stop
\Start{english}
... \verb| echo English | ...
\Stop
\end{languageswitch}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want only show one language at the same time. So I exchange the language of `\setlanguage{}`.

Comment: Why is the new environment better and why do I need it?

Comment: @ikreb You can't use `\verb` in the argument to another command.